# Lotus Notes 8.5 : Create a meeting with java

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I started to work with Lotus Notes 8.5, and i have to create meetings in Lotus by using Java, lotus.domino and Notes.jar.

So, to do this, i create a new Document and fill it with all the needed fields (i think). This is how i create my meeting :

```
Document newDocument = db.createDocument();

    newDocument.appendItemValue("Body", "Create meeting from java.");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("Notes", "Test Notes");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("Chair", "Me");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("Principal", "Me");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("$altPrincipal", "Me");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("ExcludeFromView", "D,S");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("UpdateSeq", 1);
    newDocument.appendItemValue("$CSVersion", "2");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("$SMTPKeepNotesItems", "1");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("$CSWISL", "$S:1,$L:1,$B:1,$R:1,$E:1,$W:1,$O:1,$M:1,RequiredAttendees:1,INetRequiredNames:1,AltRequiredNames:1,StorageRequiredNames:1,OptionalAttendees:1,INetOptionalNames:1,AltOptionalNames:1,StorageOptionalNames:1,ApptUNIDURL:1,STUnyteConferenceURL:1,STUnyteConferenceID:1,SametimeType:1,WhiteBoardContent:1,STRoomName:1");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("WebDateTimeInit", "1");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("OrgTable", "C0");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("$AlarmDisabled", "1");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("$HFFlags", "1");                     
    newDocument.appendItemValue("Form", "Appointment");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("$FromPreferredLanguage", "fr");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("ApptUNID", "267DEFCD6ADE4EF8C1257DF600464A1B642");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("$LangChair", "");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("AppointmentType", "3");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("$TableSwitcher", "Description");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("OnlineMeeting", "");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("From", "Me");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("AltChair", "Me");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("OnlinePlace", "");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("IsBroadcast", "");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("$ExpandGroups", 3);
    newDocument.appendItemValue("IsTeamCalendar", "");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("Importance", "");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("OrgConfidential", "");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("Subject", "Meeting test from Java");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("PreventCounter", "");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("Location", "R1");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("RoomToReserve", "");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("Resources", "");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("$PaperColor", 1);
    newDocument.appendItemValue("STRecordMeeting", "");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("WhiteBoardContent", "");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("Categories", "");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("$BorderColor", "7F96A3");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("$WatchedItems", "$S,$L,$B,$R,$E,$W,$O,$M,RequiredAttendees,INetRequiredNames,AltRequiredNames,StorageRequiredNames,OptionalAttendees,INetOptionalNames,AltOptionalNames,StorageOptionalNames,ApptUNIDURL,STUnyteConferenceURL,STUnyteConferenceID,SametimeType,WhiteBoardContent,STRoomName");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("CalForwardChairNotificationTo", "");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("ReturnReceipt", "");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("PreventDelegate", "");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("EnterSendTo", "");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("EnterCopyTo", "");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("EnterBlindCopyTo", "");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("ConferenceCallInfo", "");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("SchedulerSwitcher", "1");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("$Abstract", "");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("StartTimeZone", "Z=-1$DO=1$DL=3 -1 1 10 -1 1$ZN=Western/Central Europe");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("EndTimeZone", "Z=-1$DO=1$DL=3 -1 1 10 -1 1$ZN=Western/Central Europe");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("NewStartTimeZone", "");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("NewEndTimeZone", "");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("Encrypt", "Représentation invalide. (undefined)");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("Sign", "");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("MeetingType", "");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("$PublicAccess", "1");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("StartDate", "27/02/2015");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("StartTime", "11:00:00");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("STARTDATETIME", s.createDateTime(new GregorianCalendar(2015, 02, 27, 11, 0, 0)));
    newDocument.appendItemValue("EndDate", "27/02/2015");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("EndTime", "13:00:00");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("EndDateTime", s.createDateTime(new GregorianCalendar(2015, 02, 27, 13, 0, 0)));
    newDocument.appendItemValue("CalendarDateTime", s.createDateTime(new GregorianCalendar(2015, 02, 27, 11, 0, 0)));
    newDocument.appendItemValue("_ViewIcon", 158);
    newDocument.appendItemValue("$ShowComments", "Normal");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("$ShowDescription", "Show");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("$BusyName", "Me");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("$BusyPriority", "1");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("SequenceNum", 2);
    newDocument.appendItemValue("$CSTrack", "Imported from my contacts at 02/24/2015 14:00:17");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("$NoPurge", s.createDateTime(new GregorianCalendar(2015, 02, 27, 13, 0, 0)));
    newDocument.appendItemValue("$UpdatedBy", "Me");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("$Revisions", s.createDateTime(new GregorianCalendar(2015, 02, 24, 13, 48, 31)));
    newDocument.appendItemValue("tmpUseLongDate", s.createDateTime(new GregorianCalendar(2015, 02, 27, 11, 0, 0)));         
    newDocument.appendItemValue("tmpEventLabel", "Meeting from Java (tmpEventLabel)");  
    newDocument.appendItemValue("dispRepeatText", "Meeting from Java (dispRepeatText)");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("tmpHideTimeZone", "");
    newDocument.appendItemValue("tmpStartDate1", "27/02/2015");

    newDocument.save();
```

When i came back to Lotus, the meeting is created and shown in the calendar.
The problem is, whatever field i add or remove, when i click on this meeting, Lotus throw me an error, saying (approximate translation from french):

> Field : 'tmpStartDate1' : Temporary data required for operator or @ function

So i add this new field in java, launch the program, create a meeting, and...

> Field : 'tmpHideTimeZone' : Temporary data required for operator or @ function

For now, it is the 5th field Lotus asked me with this message....

All 'tmp******' fields are missing, but i don't know them. I thought those fields could be generated by Lotus, because of the 'tmp', but how ?

I compare with other meetings created with Lotus Notes, and there are no such 'tmp' fields.

Any ideas ?

**EDIT :**

I tried this :

```
newDocument.computeWithForm(true, true);
```

It throws a NotesException if your document isn't in a good format.
When i execute my code (approximate translation again...) :

> NotesException: Incorrect data type in the field.

I tried `computeWithForm` in another program where I create and add a contact to Lotus, and i didn't get any errors.

So indeed, there is a problem with meeting's fields...

**EDIT :**

Any new ideas ? I am a bit confused about how to develop on this software....

Comment: Is 8.5 a firm requirement?  As of 9.0 it is much easier to create a meeting in Java.  Either way, see the answers to this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21251353/how-to-create-a-lotus-notes-meeting-using-java-in-domino-designer

Comment: I know 9.0 has nice solutions, but i have to deal with 8.5.... I already saw this post, it's not the same problem and the answer of this thread show all fields of a meeting but not `tmp***********` fields.

Thx for help though.

Answer (score 0):

Items have types too ! Also a date is not a string, a date is a complicated animal, looks innocuous at first sight, but can bite very hard.

The Document.appendItemValue method coerces the item to be of `Text` type.
For date/time (not temporary ;-) items you should use [Document.ReplaceItemValueCustomData](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_REPLACEITEMVALUECUSTOMDATA_METHOD_DOC_JAVA.html) and pass it an argument of class [DateTime](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESDATETIME_CLASS_JAVA.html).

Comment: I tried : 

`DateTime startDate = s.createDateTime(new GregorianCalendar(2015, 3, 8, 11, 0, 0));
newDocument.replaceItemValueCustomData("StartDate", startDate);`

but i got a 'NotSerializableException' on the replaceItemValueCustomData line. I use lotus.Domino.DateTime.